# Chaining async functions with promises Nodejs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise, bluebird

```
var fs = require('fs');
var node_dir = require('node-dir');
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var moviesClient = new ApiClient(...)
var musicClient = new ApiClient(...)
var lib = require('./index.js');

var generateMovieMetaData = async function(){
  var json = { movies: [] };

  node_dir.files(path, function(err, files) {

    bluebird.mapSeries(files, function(file){

    return moviesClient.send(new lib.requests.Movie(file))
       .then((movie) => {
      // movie is json
      /* do some loops and work with the movie json*/
      json.movies.push(movie);
       });
    })
    .then(function(movies){
      fs.writeFile('./movies.json', JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8', (err)=>{
         if(err) console.log(err)
         else { 
          console.log('File saved');
          }
      })
      return json; // go to the next function if any
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log("Movie metadata could not be generated due to some error", err);
    });
  });
};

var generateMusicMetaData = async function(){
  var json = { music: [] };

  node_dir.subdirs(config.music.path, function(err, subdirs) {
    if (err) throw err;

    bluebird.mapSeries(subdirs, function(dir){

    return musicClient.send(new lib.requests.Album(dir))
      .then((album) => {
      // album is json
      /* do some loops and work with the album json*/
      json.music.push(album);
      });
    })
    .then(function(music){
      fs.writeFile('./music.json', JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8', (err)=>{
         if(err) console.log(err)
         else { 
          console.log('File saved');
          }
      })
      return json; // go to the next function if any
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log("Album metadata could not be generated due to some error", err);
    });
  });
};
```

Above, I have two async functions `generateMovieMetaData` and `generateMusicMetaData` each of them has `Promise.mapSeries` logic

When I call them on their own, they work correctly without throwing errors.

I want to chain the two functions in a composite function like this

```
var generateMetaData = function(){
  generateMusicMetaData()
   .then(() => generateMovieMetaData());
}
generateMetaData();
```

Calling `generateMetaData` returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error from the first function:

```
Album metadata could not be generated due to some error TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
[0]     at musicClient.send.then (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/server.js:179:23)
[0]     at tryCatcher (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
[0]     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:51
2:31)
[0]     at Promise._settlePromise (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
[0]     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
[0]     at Promise._settlePromises (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
[0]     at Async._drainQueue (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
[0]     at Async._drainQueues (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
[0]     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/mnt/c/Users/ridhwaan/Source/homehost/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/a
sync.js:17:14)
[0]     at runCallback (timers.js:756:18)
[0]     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:717:5)
[0]     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:697:5)
```

---

**EDIT 1:** Ok I changed the code to look easier. Am getting the same error dunno why
Logging shows that `bluebird.mapSeries` in both functions is happening at the same time, then throwing the error

Comment: You forgot to return something from your first `.then()` callback. Therefore, in the next `.then()` callback in the chain, the input is `undefined`.

Comment: Also I whole-heatedly dis-recommend mixing callback-based and promise-based code like that.

Comment: the error implies that `json.movies` is not an array - yet, that's not the case, because it is an array - besides the fact that the code in the question has a bunch of `...` which makes it "unparseable", it also has missing `))` in one if statement - so, chances are, the code is quite different from the **actual** code you are having an issue with - based on the alleged error, I'd say that's the case

Comment: I changed the code to be easier. dunno what the root cause of the error is

Comment: `generateMusicMetaData()`  does not return anything.  You need to return a promise from it.  You will have to redesign your code to only use promises not a mix of callbacks and promises to do this cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the original implementations that make it so they don't return a promise that is resolved when all the async operations in each function are completely done.  Because of that, you can't coordinate them with other asynchronous operations.

So first let's fix the implementation of your two functions.  It's a lot simpler to just use ES6 async/await for that implementation:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
const node_dir = Promise.promisifyAll(require('node-dir'));
let moviesClient = new ApiClient(...)
let musicClient = new ApiClient(...)
let lib = require('./index.js');


async function generateMovieMetaData(path) {
    var json = { movies: [] };

    let files = await node_dir.filesAsync(path);

    for (let f of files) {
        let movie = await moviesClient.send(new lib.requests.Movie(f));
        json.movies.push(movie);
    }

    await fs.writeFileAsync('./movies.json', JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8').catch(err => {
        console.log("Movie metadata could not be generated due to some error", err);
        throw err;
    });
    return json;
}

async generateMusicMetaData function(path) {
    var json = { music: [] };

    let files = await node_dir.subdirsAsync(path);

    for (let d of dirs) {
        let album = await musicClient.send(new lib.requests.Album(d));
        json.music.push(album);
    }

    await fs.writeFileAsync('./music.json', JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8').catch(err => {
        console.log("Album metadata could not be generated due to some error", err);
        throw err;
    });
    return json;
}
```

Note that there are no plain callbacks at all in this implementation.  Everything is done using promises and asynchronous operations that don't naturally return promises were "promisified".  I used Bluebird here for that since you already showed you were using it, but you could have also used `util.promisify()` which is built into node.js now.

Now, we have it so each of these functions returns a promise that resolves with the json and onlyh resolves when all the asynchronous operations inside are done.  That sets it up well for sequencing using async/await:

```
function async generateMetaData(path){
    let music = await generateMusicMetaData(path);
    let movie = await generateMovieMetaData(path);
    return {music, movie};
}

generateMetaData(path).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But, since these appear to be two completely unrelated operations, you could do them in parallel:

```
function generateMetaData(path){
    return Promise.all([generateMusicMetaData(path), generateMovieMetaData(path)]).then(([music, movie]) => {
        return {music, movie};
    });
}

generateMetaData(path).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt resolving a promise in each function, I only had a return. I changed the line where I have `return json;` to `resolve(json);`

```
var generateMusicMetaData = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  ...
  r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶j̶s̶o̶n̶;̶
  resolve(json);
  ...
  });
};

var generateMovieMetaData = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  ...
  r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶j̶s̶o̶n̶;̶
  resolve(json);
  ...
  });
};
```

then i have

```
var generateMetaData = function(){
  generateMusicMetaData()
    .then(function(result) { 
      return generateMovieMetaData();
    });
}
```

Comment: The code you show in your question does not show the `return new Promise()` stuff at all. The code in your question is not returning anything from your two `generateXXX()` functions.

Comment: code in the question has a return json (wrong) but was missing promise constructor and resolve. I added it for the fix

Comment: Using a mix of regular callbacks and promises and then wrapping all that with another promise is considered an anti-pattern and, while you don't show the actual code you're using, the reason it's an anti-pattern is it is really easy to make mistakes with error handling.  You really ought to promisify all the regular callback functions you're using and then just chain promises inside your function without any `new Promise(...)`.